# Unix pipes question

Tags: unix, pipe

I would like to know, if there is a way to print the pipes associated with a process, like "ipcs -s" for semaphores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing that comes to mind is `lsof -p <pid>|grep FIFO`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. Pipes are file handles, and anything that shows open filehandles (lsof, for instance) will show them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, pipes are just open file descriptors in *nix, so you could ask it to print the open file descriptors for a specific process with:

```
lsof -p <process id>
```

I don't know if there's a way to filter by pipe creation, though.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, if you're on Linux but don't have lsof installed, you can do:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd
```